# A second non-linear x2-axis, depending on the 1st one values

Tags: gnuplot, axis

I plotted a figure with a classical x-axis, let's say from 0 to 25.

I'd like to have the x2-axis having the sqrt of x1-values and I didn't find anything about how to do it.

With my values here, x2range would be [0:5]
But tics shouldn't be linear, tha's why i didn't succeed to make it.

x2-tic 5 would match with 25, x2-tic 4 with 16, 3 with 9, etc.

Any Help ?
I hope there's a not-too-hard way to do this

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That can be done since **gnuplot 5** with the command `set link`, which links a secondary axis to the respective primary axis via a transformation function:

```
set xrange [0:25]
set link x2 via sqrt(x) inverse x**2
set x2tics
set xtics nomirror
plot x
```

[image]

The commands as given above will generate a warning because the mapping isn't unique. But you can ignore that warning as long as your xrange starts at value greater or equal to zero.

For **gnuplot 4.6** you must place all x2tics manually:

```
set xrange [0:25]
set x2range [0:25]
set xtics nomirror
# delete all automatic tics but the one at 0
set x2tics (0) 
# add all other tics
set for [i=1:5] x2tics add (sprintf('%d', i) i**2)
plot x
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm trying to do but... what if I have to use GNUPlot 4.6 ? :D